# Should my intermediate table contain a composite PK or a unique index

Tags: sql-server, database-design

Let's say I have a `Products` table, `ProductsCategory` table and a `Category` table.

The `ProductsCategory` table has two columns: `ProductID` and `CategoryID`. Should I be using a composite primary key or a unique index on the two columns?

Additionally if I use the index, I can make it a unique index or a key.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Might as well use a composite key - no need to add a unique index when you already have the uniqueness semantics of a composite primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You must create two way foreign key both table with on delete cascade option.
Because if you delete one of categories then it must remove relational rows on ProductCategory.

i mean you can use like this :

```
alter table ProductsCategory add constraint ForeignKey1 foreign key (ProductId) references Products (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE;
alter table ProductsCategory add constraint ForeignKey2 foreign key (CategoryId) references Category (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```